# Ambiguous Column Name: Why is it ambiguous in certain circumstances?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As you know, if we select two tables whereas we have the same column name, we get the error:

> 'Ambiguous column name 'ColumnName''

**I already know that setting the alias does fix this issue.**

However, it seems if the name of the column is **not** in the SELECT statement, then it works for SQL Server 2008 R2 (on my database). Compatibility-Level is set to 100.

So the following statement DOES work:

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t2.ID = t1.ID) 
ORDER BY ID
```

But apparently in other circumstances the above statement does return an error (I know this because it happened at the customer's site). Also on SQL Fiddle it returns the error both on SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012.

Does anybody know **why** or **in which circumstances** the above query still returns the error?

My guess is that it's a matter of version or settings on the SQL Server.

**Note:** The linked duplicate did solve my problem. Compatibility level was set to 80. Changing it to 100 solved the problem.

Comment: @SynerCoder please read my question carefully again.

Comment: Is this part right: FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table1 ON Table2 t2? Do you join Table1 with Table1 on purpose?

Comment: @Ziouas ah no, thanks. I just want to demonstrate my problem

Comment: And the error you get on that `customer's site` is also about having `Ambiguous column name` ?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty please read the question carefully again. :)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste yes, exactly the same error. Unfortunately I have no information about the SQL Server installed there.

Comment: Can you tell us what version is having the issue, since you indicate you think it may be version dependent?

Comment: @FabianBigler: What is the exact problem here?

Comment: You need to post the rest of your code since you have an Open ) I'm assuming we can not see the problem.

Comment: If you have the same column in 2 tables then ordering by it (without an alias) never works afaik, independent of version or settings.

Comment: @JNK I'm afraid I can't. I wondered if this error occurs on your SQL Server versions somwhere. Or maybe if it's a setting on SQL Server.

Comment: @FabianBigler It turns out to be a duplicate of an old question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm not so sure it is a duplicate of that question. No mention (in this question) that the same query works in one server and doesn't in another.

Comment: @ypercube In the very first sentence: "This simple query throws the "Ambiguous column name TaskID" error on one db-server only."

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Where is that *"on one db-server only"*? I can't find it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight OK, I meant in **this** question. But reading again, I suppose you are right, it has *"(I know this because it happened at the customer's site)."* I agree, seems like a duplicate.

Comment: @ypercube Ah, I see what you mean. OP supplied a hint in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019550/ambiguous-column-name-why-is-it-ambiguous-in-certain-circumstances?noredirect=1#comment33378045_22019619). Since he's talking about a server where this statement does work, there must also be a server on which it does not work, otherwise there wouldn't be a question.

Answer (score 9):

You will get this error WHENEVER your SELECT, JOIN ON, WHERE, GROUP, HAVING do not fully qualify the column **AND** there are more than 1 columns with that name that you have JOINed to.

The ORDER BY Name example works because ORDER BY will allow you to use the name of the column in the SELECT, for example this would work in the **ORDER BY** but not anywhere else in the SQL statement.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name AS [CrazyName]
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN Table1 
  ON Table2 t2 (t2.ID = t1.ID) 
ORDER BY [CrazyName]
```

Comment: I already know that. but in SQL Server 2008 R2 the above statement DOES works (!!!) why?

Comment: Because your SELECT has NAME in it, you can ORDER BY using ALIAS so it is finding NAME in the SELECT it will use it unless you specifically indicate a TABLE prefix.

Comment: But the t1.Name isn't an alias, it's just the name of the column, so that doesn't hold here

Comment: it doesn't matter, it's the name in the SELECT

Comment: I think this makes sense. The Order by is `ORDER BY NAME` which is not an alias and does not specify a table thus ambiguous.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is the only clause that can use a column alias because it is processed last, so this is probably accurate.

Answer (score 3):

ORDER BY is processed as the last step in the order of operations for a SQL Statement; see http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm for an better explanation.

SQL statements are processed in the following order:

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

What this means is that the ambiguity has been resolved by the time of the SELECT statement, and so the ORDER BY clause references the SELECT statement.  If the statement is ambiguous at any point before then, an error will be thrown.

Comment: That's not entirely true I believe, because you can have different columns with the same ALIAS in a SELECT statement

Comment: @NickyvV In that case, you get the the ambiguous column error (for the amibguouity in the ORDER BY clause): **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/611b7/1)**

Comment: @ypercube Yes, that was my point.. :)

Comment: In that case, you've introduced ambiguity at the SELECT clause that didn't exist previously; the ORDER BY clause is thus affected (and is the only clause affected).  Principle still holds true; each order of operations expect the previous order to have resolved ambiguity.

Comment: @Stuart. Not exactly. The only place where the ambiguity can be resolved is at the `SELECT` clause, either by using different aliases or by selecting one of the (many) columns with same name. So, in all clauses you have to use table aliases. Except in `ORDER BY` and only when the ambiguity has been resolved in the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the logical execution of the query , ORDER BY us the last phase. So ORDER BY takes the column names/alias names present in the select by default

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/