# Ambigous column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm confused by the behavior of `ORDER BY` with SQL Server 2014.

I have a query like this:

```
select a.Name, b.Status
from a
join b on a.parent_id = b.parent_id
order by parent_id
```

This query will throw an error

> Ambiguous column name 'parent_id'

which makes sense because the column appears in both tables. What I don't understand is that if I list one of the those columns in the `SELECT` like so:

```
select a.Name, b.*
from a
join b on a.parent_id = b.parent_id
order by parent_id
```

it works.

I understood `ORDER BY` to be a 'last in' type of operation, which is why you can order by a column ordinal. And I understood that you could order by a column not listed in the `SELECT` clause. So, why does it throw an error in one case and not the other? And is the ordering different if I were to list the column from table a in the `SELECT` vs listing it in the `ORDER BY` from table b?

EDIT: the answers to this question: [Ambiguous Column Name: Why is it ambiguous in certain circumstances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019550/ambiguous-column-name-why-is-it-ambiguous-in-certain-circumstances) explains my problem, but just to be clear, it's not version dependent like that question implies.

Comment: because `Order by` is logically processed after `select`, so when the column is present in `select`, then the column in order by it will be considered from `select`. When the order by column is not part of select then it will not know from which table to pick from so the Ambiguous error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous Column Name: Why is it ambiguous in certain circumstances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019550/ambiguous-column-name-why-is-it-ambiguous-in-certain-circumstances)

Comment: You can also compare the behaviour of `order by 0+parent_id`

Comment: @MartinSmith what does the addition in the order by produce?

Comment: It's just to demonstrate that if you include the column name in any type of expression it is no longer resolved from the column alias and you would go back to the "ambiguous" error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say `order by parent_id`, then the SQL engine has to look for `parent_id`.  There are two possibilities:

- The `FROM` clause
- The `SELECT` clause

Without a table alias, SQL Server will look in the `SELECT` first.  Voila! If it finds `parent_id` there, then it is done.  It only detects the duplicate if it  has to go to the `FROM` clause for resolution.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I tried it and I now realize that I can order not just by ordinals, but also by column alias names. And if I alias the parent_id in the above example then the ambiguous error returns. Thanks!